# ListView. Hot to highlight whole listview item when touching on it

Tags: android, listview

There is `ListView` with items which contains `TextView`.
When you are touching listview item and hold the finger on it, listview item is highlighted a little.

But if textview contains just a few letters - not all row is highlighted.

Is any simple solution (some xml property, etc) to highlight whole row?

[image]

Comment: Do you have any xml code for the list view?

Comment: show me your listview code..

Comment: Try to make your `TextView` width `fill_parent` and then check @vetalitet

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Hi Set This Code In Your Xml Of ListView
=================================
<ListView android:id="@+id/list1"
         android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"/>
```

Comment: Yes. That is what I wanted. I paid all my attention on ListView items and completely forget to change any properties of parent. Thanks!

Comment: Alway Welcome!It Happened Some Times.

Answer (score 1):

you try to make listview width android:layout_width="fill_parent" .And also if u are using custom adapter for (images and text) -make layout width size-fill parent or match parent

Answer (score 0):

Set android:layout_width attribute of parent Layout tag to fill_Parent for in xml for Listview.